# Background image being tiled

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this image being pulled from a url:

[image]

---

And I'm using the following code to display it as background, inside my component `render()`:

**Field.jsx**

```
const { players } = this.props;

return (
  <div className="back" style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('https://url.svg')" } }>
      <div className="field-wrapper" >
         <Output output={this.props.strategy} />
           <div className="row"> {this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 5).map((player,i) => (
               <Position key={i}>{player.name}</Position>))} 
           </div>
 </div>
)
```

---

What am I missing?

But the image is being tiled, like so:

[image]

This is **Field.css**:

```
.back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.field-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

.field-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get rid of the inline style and do something like this:

```
 .back {
        background: url(pathToYourImg) no-repeat center; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover; 
        -moz-background-size: cover; 
        -o-background-size: cover; 
        background-size: cover;
   }
```

Comment: must let go of `center fixed`, though

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help:

`background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;`

you can find more in:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp